# Import module that contains only a javascript file

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules

I´m trying to import on my Angular component a module but it only contains a Javascript file and no typescript typings.

I did the following:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

declare function require(name:string);
const HC_Regression = require('highcharts-regression');
HC_Regression(Highcharts);
```

It works but it feels hacky plus I get a lot of warnings.

First because the function require as explicite type any and second because the function require doesn´t return anything.

Is there a better way of doing this?

[How to use Highcharts regression plugin to plot a trend line using angular 8 wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995273/how-to-use-highcharts-regression-plugin-to-plot-a-trend-line-using-angular-8-wra)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file called `highcharts-regression.d.ts` which would be a TypeScript typings file. If you didn't want any typings, all you would need in the file would be

```
declare module 'highcharts-regression';
```

or you could take the time to write the typings. Then, in your `tsconfig.json`  `typeRoots` field, which is an array, you would add a value of the directory that your `.d.ts` file is in. Then, when you import the module, the warnings should go away, but you won't have any types so it will all implicitly be any. I would recommend putting your types in a different directory, for example a root subdirectory under `src` or something so that it does not get mixed up with the rest of your code.

Comment: It complains that could not find a declaration for module ´highcarts-regression´

Comment: That probably means typescript can't find the file... I would check to make sure that the types folder you put the file in is in the typescript `typeRoots` along with `node_modules/@types`. Here's the docs, I'm not sure what else would work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots